# SQL update multiple rows without hard code each value

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to update thousands of rows, but type in each value is time-comsuming

[image]

my code

```
UPDATE #table
SET city = 'New York'
WHERE city is null
AND store_id = '22'
```

expected result

```
store_id   city      state
22        New york   NY
22        New york   NY
22        New york   NY
33         LA        CA
33         LA        CA
```

how to modify the code so that I don't have to type in 'New York' etc. each time? thank you

Comment: Your question is quite unclear: you want to update every record where store_id = "X" and city is blank/null with the value of the first city? Do all the different store_id have always oly one city name related to them? Are all these values fixed or they come from another table?

Comment: @JoshPart the 'New York' does not have to be in the first record, because there're many rows that have 'New York', yes, always one id tie to one city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what comes to my mind, but I believe there could be a more optimized way to do it:

```
WITH cteCities(store_id, city, state) AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT store_id, city, state FROM #table WHERE city IS NOT NULL)
UPDATE #table
SET city = cte.city, state = cte.state
FROM cteCities cte
INNER JOIN #table
ON cte.store_id = #table.store_id
WHERE #table.city IS NULL
```

Comment: it works in SQL server, but not in AWS, I change the CTE to a #temp table, but AWS give another error "[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: table name "#t" specified more than once;"

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #t (store_id varchar(20),city varchar(20),[state] varchar(20))
INSERT INTO #t VALUES
('22', 'new', 'NY'),
('22', null, null),
('22', null, null),
('33', null, null),
('33', 'LA', 'CA')
;


WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT store_id, city, [state] FROM #t WHERE city IS NOT NULL
)
UPDATE #t
SET city = CTE.city, [state] = CTE.[state]
FROM CTE
INNER JOIN #t
ON CTE.store_id = #t.store_id
WHERE #t.city IS NULL
```